# How to create a scrollView in react native which is initially set at the bottom half of screen?

Tags: react-native

[image]

As seen in the image above, I want to display two views on the screen and when the user tries to pull up the bottom View It should cover the entire screen and the bottom view would hide below it. I want the help regarding creation of this kind of layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-reanimated` to create that kind of animation.

Check out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNw8lPdD4H4. You will get a better understanding to create that type of animation.

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could show how this answers the Question.